# Jetty autorefresh/autoload for quick testing

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty

From PHP I am used to just saving the `.php` file and reloading the browser after modifying the source file. How can I do this with JAVA and Jetty? When I save my webservice I currently stop the jetty server and start it again with `mvn jetty:start`, whats the non-complicated way of getting where I want to go?

Comment: jsps or servletS? are you using an IDE?

Comment: Servlets with Eclipse, I run Jetty with mvn jetty:start from the shell though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the difference between PHP and Java is that the former is an interpreter, whereas the latter is compiler-based (binary). In PHP the code is validated upon execution, whereas in Java you need to compile it first. In Java, when you use JSP-s, it is possible to just save them and reload them by hitting the refresh button in your browser (if, of course, it's running in development mode). If you change classes, you need to restart your server. If your're just changing web resources, you can simply define the `scanInterval` variable for the Jetty Maven plugin. That will takes care of updating your web resources.

[EDITED] Added the code from Jack Murphy's comment below, so that it is correctly formatted.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The code to what you propose is modifying the pom.xml as follows `<plugins>
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
          </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 20):

From the command line:

```
mvn -Djetty.reload=automatic -Djetty.scanIntervalSeconds=2 jetty:run
```

If you are depending on Eclipse, ensure you have **Project->Build Automatically** enabled so that the classes are recompiled.

I haven't tried the configuration file approach, but more details of Jack Murphy's approach can be found here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin

Comment: Excellent! This reloads both static resources and recompiled classes - perfect.

Comment: Should I have to paste those command line arguments in the Run Configurations -> J2EE Preview at localhost -> Arguments -> Program Arguments? Is is ok? Thanks.

Comment: But the server is being restarted here? Which again takes up a lot of time. What is the point in doing this here?

Comment: Because Java is not an interpreted language, the classes will have to reload. I agree that this makes Java web dev a pain, so I tend to rely on unit tests as often as possible for quick testing. My answer is intended to be run from the command line, but could be configured in Eclipse under the "Maven Build" section in Run Configurations (with the M2E plugin)

Comment: if server startup takes a lot of time, that's probably because you do some classpath scanning for annotated service classes and the like. I'd prefer having an embedded jetty instance without running jetty-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer. in IntelliJ, the Resource/class/front end modification can be refresh without restart server by following steps.

1: Edit 'On Update Action' section in server configuration.
[image]

2: Every time when you did above modification. Click the last button.

[image]

And refresh browser. That's it.